# SELECT DISTINCT ordering rows by order of appearance of the field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, distinct

I have this data

```
Id          Campo
----------- ----------
1           id_recibo
2           col_2
3           col_65
4           UNDCAP
5           id_recibo
6           col_2
7           col_65
8           UNDCAP
```

And I need to do something like `SELECT DISTINCT` obtaining the data in order of appearance and not in the ascending order by default that is obtained.

If I do a `SELECT DISTINCT` I get this:

```
campo
--------
col_2
col_65
id_recibo
UNDCAP
```

Here the code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Campo VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (Campo)
VALUES ('id_recibo'), ('col_2'), ('col_65'), ('UNDCAP'),
       ('id_recibo'), ('col_2'), ('col_65'), ('UNDCAP')

SELECT * FROM #tmp

SELECT DISTINCT campo FROM #tmp
```

The result I need is like this:

```
campo
----------
id_recibo
col_2
col_65
UNDCAP
```

I tried some like this, but It doesn't work, because the order is variable:

```
SELECT 
    A.Campo AS NuevoOrden
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         CAMPO
     FROM 
         #tmp) A
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: to avoid dropping a temp table just use table variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
select campo
from t
group by campo
order by min(id);
```

Comment: Yes! It is! This is just what I needed. I got the result I expected.